# writing query for below employee table such that the out put should be

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

4)  Employee table

```
Name      Location
 A              Hyd
 B              Bng
 C              Hyd
 D              Bng
```

The o/p should be

```
Name
                Hyd                 Bng
A              1                       0
B              0                       1
C              1                       0
D              0                       1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `CASE` expressions here:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    CASE WHEN Location = 'Hyd' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Hyd,
    CASE WHEN Location = 'Bng' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Bng
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    Name;
```